# Growing stone fruit (peach) from Pit

Tags: fruit-trees, seeds, germination, peaches

(I'm in the Southern Hemisphere, in equivalent of hardiness zone 9B - I have a thriving plum tree on my property, and previously a peach tree which died of old age).

Thus far I have taken a couple of pits (maybe more to come?), removed as much pulp as I could by hand by scrubbing pit under running water -  and dried them overnight at just above ambient temperature in an area with good airflow.    **I'm not sure what to do next or when to do it.**   (Its early autumn here, so about 180 days to spring).

General advice would be appreciated - but specifically I'm wanting help with -

1. How long do I leave the pits to dry?   Does this matter much?
2. Do I remove the seeds from the pits now, or should I wait 2-3 months - if I should wait, how do I store pits (fridge? Moisture?) ?
3. I understand I then put the seeds (or should it be whole pits?) in the fridge in a moist ziplock bag and they should start germinating in 3 months.  One video talked about adding cinnamon powder as an antifungal - is that correct?  (I know it as a growth hormone for cuttings).  If not Cinnamon are there any other household things I should use like dilute bleach?
4. If I start the process of putting seeds into fridge to germinate now they should start germinating at beginning of Winter?  Is this a problem?   If not, do I transplant them to soil indoors or outdoors?  [ Indoors ambient temps will be 10c-23c, Outdoors -3 to 23c or so with lots of rain ]

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have pests likely to dig them out (squirrels, etc.) or to take measures to protect them from those, such as wire mesh over the bed, you can plant them in the ground now and wait for spring.

Refrigerating the moistened seeds is essentially artifically overwintering them.

No idea about cinnamon, etc. but that's an example of why "one question per question" is preferred here.

Comment: Ta. Definately dont want to plant them yet - I expect to grow them in pots for a while - maybe use them as root stock fot grafting.

Comment: Dig holes in ground. Plunge pots into holes in ground. Fill pots with potting mix and seed. Place wire over, secure with pins or rocks. Possibly mulch. Supposedly seedling peaches grow close to type to the parent.